# Read content from email with line breaks

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have to read content from javax.mail.Message with line breaks. 
At the moment I use this algorithm, I have found it on stackoverflow but after read content by it the content doesn't has new lines, so when I read string a Scanner.nextLine() read only one line.

```
private String getTextFromMimeMultipart(
        MimeMultipart mimeMultipart) throws Exception{
    String result = "";
    int count = mimeMultipart.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
        if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
            result = result + "\n" + bodyPart.getContent();
        } else if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/html")) {
            String html = (String) bodyPart.getContent();
            result = result + "\n" + org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(html).text();
        } else if (bodyPart.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart){
            result = result + getTextFromMimeMultipart((MimeMultipart)bodyPart.getContent());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you are doing with the content read. It is possible that if you´re on Windows, it´s just using \n instead of \r\n. But it´s just a guess. Please rephrase your question and supply more information.

Comment: Ok, I have resolved my problem. String doesn't has new lines becouse Jsoup.parse() removes all new lines. This is solution   `String html = (String) bodyPart.getContent();
                String parsedHtml = Jsoup.parse(html.replaceAll("(?i)<br[^>]*>", "br2n")).text();
                result = result + System.getProperty("line.separator") + parsedHtml.replaceAll("br2n", System.getProperty("line.separator")); `

Comment: Please add this as an answer to your own question, this way it helps other users searching for a similar problem.

Comment: @DamianU your question and answer must be separated, please copy your answer down below these comments

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have resolved my problem. String doesn't has new lines becouse Jsoup.parse() removes all new lines. This is solution:

```
String html = (String) bodyPart.getContent();
String parsedHtml = Jsoup.parse(html.replaceAll("(?i)<br[^>]*>","br2n")).text();
result = result + System.getProperty("line.separator") + parsedHtml.replaceAll("br2n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```